# Does Cast Iron legacy version 5 support TLS?

Tags: ssl, salesforce, poodle-attack

I inherited a Cast Iron appliance which reports that it is version 5.0.1.5 - several years old and off support.

This is mostly used to talk to Salesforce, who just sent us an email saying they are turning off SSL 3.0 in a few weeks. POODLE.

Can anybody tell me if this version of Cast Iron supports TLS and will continue to work when SFDC disables SSL 3.0? Or point me to something that tells me how to check this myself? I'm drawing a blank with Google..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: yes, old Cast Iron version 5.0.1 does support TLS 1.0.

Salesforce shut SSL 3.0 off this past weekend on all their sandbox instances and our CI integrations are still happy.

Answer (score 0):

Better upgrade fast.. this broke a client instance..

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21687945

Answer (score 0):

Castiron version below 6.1.0.12 do not support TLS. Once salesforce switched off ssl in sandboxes our orchs (all 150) of them would not connect to salesforce.

We are upgrading to version 7.

Comment: That's very strange - it definitely does work on our version 5 integrations.